# Unable to upload bundle with InstantApp and installable app

Tags: android, google-play, android-instant-apps, android-app-bundle

I have an app that has a base module `:app` in which AndroidManifest.xml does not have any activities.

I have another module `:main_app` in which AndroidManifest.xml has a launcher activity.

Then I have another module `:instant_experience` in which AndroidManifest.xml has an activity for the instant app. This activity has `intent-filter` set up to be triggered from a specific host.

When I upload the bundle to the Play Store, I am getting the following error:

> You must provide an entry point for your Instant App APKs. It can be
> either a URL, or an Activity with ACTION_MAIN and CATEGORY_LAUNCHER.

FYI, the dependency graph is `:main_app` and `:instant_experience` are depending on `:app` module.

Please help!

Comment: The best way to get useful answers is to actually add all three AndroidManifest files here. It allows us to see what you tried, and will certainly result in more help. Additionally, the build.gradle files allow us to see which plugins have been used. E.g. the old and deprecated instant app plugin, or the dynamic feature plugin. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add "DEFAULT" category to your intent filter in `:instant_experience`?

Here is what we have for our app, in our instant module's `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:dist="http://schemas.android.com/apk/distribution"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="a.b.c.instant">

    <dist:module
        dist:instant="true"
        dist:title="@string/module_instant_title">
        <dist:delivery>
            <dist:install-time />
        </dist:delivery>
        <dist:fusing dist:include="true" />
    </dist:module>

    <application>
        <activity
            android:name=".InstantActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Splashscreen"
            android:visibleToInstantApps="true"
            tools:targetApi="o">

            <meta-data
                android:name="default-url"
                android:value="https://www.example.org/foo/bar" />

            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                    android:scheme="http" />
                <data
                    android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="www.example.org"
                    android:pathPrefix="/foo/" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Note that we used `android:autoVerify="true"` in the intent filter to support [App Links](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links).
Looks like we also needed to add `android:visibleToInstantApps="true"` to our instant activity node, but I don't remember why...

Does this example helps you fix your situation? Otherwise, would you mind updating your question with `:instant_experience`'s `AndroidManifest.xml`?